# htaccess for subdomain and url rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm in trouble with this .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} appname.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !appname/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appname/$1 [L]
```

In the document root (not really the root document, let's say a v-domain folder) i have this folder called 'appname'. On appname.domain.com everything shows up fine as it should. Now my problem is when I want to do something like this

```
http://appname.domain.com/somefolder
```

I don't want the url to be rewritten to
    appname.domain.com/appname/somefolder
In the url bar.
Any help?

Update:
In the document root i have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^v-domain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /v-domain/$1 [L]
```

In v-domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v-domain/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} appname.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !appname/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appname/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} appname.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^appname/(.+)$ http://appname.domain.com/$1/    [R=301,L]
###################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} appname2.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !appname2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appname2/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} appname2.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^appname2/(.+)$ http://appname2.domain.com/$1/  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Those rules seem to work like you've intended when I put them in my .htaccess file.

Comment: Try to make a dir in your subdomain folder with an index in it and then try to reach that path. You will see the url being rewritten in the ugly mentioned way "appname.domain.com/appname/somefolder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to make a dir in your subdomain folder with an index in it and then try to reach that path. You will see the url being rewritten in the ugly mentioned way "appname.domain.com/appname/somefolder"

That sounds like it's [mod_dir's DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) interferring. With DirectorySlash turned on, if mod_dir sees that a request is made for a directory and is missing the trailing slash, it **redirects** the browser to the equivalent URL to include the trailing slash.

Something you can do is to turn `DirectorySlash off` but there's a disclosure concern when it comes to DirectoryIndex'ing (see the DirectorySlash entry in mod_dir). You could try adding some rules to do this redirect for you but make sure to redirect without the `/appname/` bit in the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} appname.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^appname/(.+)$ http://appname.domain.com/$1/    [R=301,L]
```

This basically checks if the request is for the host `appname.domain.com`, that the requested entity is a directory, that the request does **not** end with a trailing slash, and if the request has already been rewritten for `/appname/` redirect the browser to the same URL (without appname) but with a trailing slash. After the redirect, the first rule that you have will internally rewrite the URI to include the /appname/, but since the request now ends with a trailing slash, mod_dir should ignore it.

Comment: In this way `appname.domain.com/folder` (without the trailing slash) will end up with a forbidden error.

Comment: Everything works fine if the appname folder is placed in the root directory. In my case my v-domain folder in the document root contains all the subdomain folders in it e.g. /v-domain/appname, /v-domain/appname2, /v-domain/appname3. How can i edit these rules to work properly with these paths? e.g.

`/v-domain/appname/folder`.

Comment: In addition i'd like the two parts of the url rewrite to be separated. In my document root I have this htaccess to redirect all the non subdomain request to the v-domain folder:

    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^v-domain/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /v-domain/$1 [L]`

Then i'd like to put the subdomains rewriting rules in the v-domain folder.
@Jon

Comment: try adding an `RewriteBase /v-domain/` to the top of your rules (in the .htaccess file in the v-domain folder).

Comment: Thank you very much. The last problem i noticed is that when i have a folder called appname in the document root (same name as the subdomain folder in v-domain) the rewrite rules redirect appname.domain.com to /appname instead of /v-domain/appname. dont understand why

Comment: Can you post an update to your question with all of your rules? Code doesn't format very well in comments.

Comment: In the .htaccess that's in your document root, you want the regex to include a leading slash: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v-domain/`

Comment: that didn't help. still redirecting to /appname if an "appname" folder exists in the document root.